# Getting "Tokens Unavailable" in 0X instant

Tags: erc-20, 0x

I have deployed both 0x-launch-kit-backend and 0x-launch-kit-frontend in my local system
I can able to create a sell order. It is listed in orders
I am running things in Ropsten Testnet

In 0X Instant Html code . I replace my relayer URL in orderSource and mention networkId:3

I can get values in record in asset_pairs api

While run instant in-browser got "Tokens Unavailable".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

0x Instant doesn't have Ropsten testnet tokens as a default. Only Mainnet and Kovan.

You can add additional asset data to Instant in these cases:

```js
zeroExInstant.render({
    orderSource: RELAYER_URL,
    availableAssetDatas: ['0xf47261b0000000000000000000000000744d70fdbe2bc4cf95131626614a1764df805b9e'],
    additionalAssetMetaDataMap: {
        '0xf47261b0000000000000000000000000744d70fdbe2bc4cf95131626614a1764df805b9e': {
            assetProxyId: '0xf47261b0', // ERC20 Proxy Id
            decimals: 18,
            primaryColor: '#F2F7FF', // Optional
            symbol: 'XXX',
            name: 'My Custom Token'
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I change the network to the kovan testnet. Still, I face the same problem.

Comment: I can manually mention assetData in HTML code and get the required data.

Comment: How can I set this token detect automatically

Comment: What is the Token? We do not provide an exhaustive list of all tokens on all networks for 0x Instant. This is left up to the implementor in most cases.